# Running tcpdump on remote machine with no tty using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to start tcpdump on several remote machines to perform some network analysis with a script, but I'm failing to run it correctly. The command I would like to use is:

> ssh user@host "nohup sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump udp -l -s 68 -n -v -i eth0 1>tcpdump.txt 2>tcpdump.err &"

With the intention to start tcpdump remotely, pipe the results to file and return immediately. Not having a keyboard installed on the remote machine, all I get is

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

written in tcpdump.err. I also tried:

- writing the command in a bash script and running the script remotely
- enclosing the sudo part in the 'script' command (script -c 'nohup sudo...')

but with no success. Is there some other alternatives I can try?

Comment: Have you tried ssh -t to force pseudo-tty allocation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that alternative: I have already tried
using the -t option, both once and twice ("ssh -t -t ...")

Answer (score 0):

You're using sudo in your command, which will require authentication, unless configured otherwise on the remote host. You'll be forced to enter a password to authenticate unless you try something like

```
user NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

in the sudoers file on the remote host.

This can have serious security implications; if someone were to hack into the system as this user (or just sit down at one of their logged in consoles), they could tcpdump all traffic to/from that host without authenticating as root or that user.

Check out the tag_spec section of [the sudoers man page](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) for more details.